How Do I implement spring security in all microservices
I have implemented spring security in an authorization service where I am generating my token but how do I implement it in all my microservices.
There are a lot codes online but unable to find for the latest version of spring boot 3+
At present I am using sending jwt token at auth header writing some code
@PostMapping("/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addWishlist(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, @PathVariable String username, @RequestBody MovieDto movie){
        if (jwtService.isTokenValid(token.substring(7),username)){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(wishlistService.addWishlist(username,movie),HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        throw new UnAuthorizedException("Unauthorized token access add movie");
    }

I want to achieve something like below using spring security
@GetMapping("/validate")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MEMBER') && #username == authentication.principal.username")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> validate(@RequestParam String username) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(username+" Authorized", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

here is the actual source code link to GitHub Repository
I want to implement security in wishlist and userprofile
Solution to implement spring security just by using jwt token without connecting to database using the latest spring boot 3+ and spring version 6

You should create a filter that can extend from OncePerRequestFilter and add it into SecurityFilterChain. Your filter have to do a request to your authorization service and get some info about user by token. The next step is fill SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() object so spring security will able to recognize users' permissions

this is actually a little big process that I had to do because I am using granted authorities but was able to achieve it in the latest version of spring boot Source code for it

A good approach would be to use Spring Cloud Gateway to get all requests to all microservices and then pass them to the corresponding microservice.
Spring Cloud Gateway should pass HTTP Header information that will contain an Access Token for every service to receive and use for user validation. You will be able to have stuff like hasRole('MEMBER')

Yes I have Implemented it. That is good process centralizing security but we will still have issues, cause if we access the endpoint directly from microservices we will be able to access them and further more, it won't check the username, I want a process where other users should not access other user details

It looks like you need to build a multi-tenant system. This is beyond the spring security framework's core capabilities. If you want to let users see their data only, it's on you to track who is the owner of the object/resource. And have code to make sure that the user requesting something will get only what belongs to them.

&& #username == authentication.principal.username") this checks the username matching with token subject
